# Problem in creating Force.com Project on Eclipse

Tags: force.com

I am new in salesforce, I am trying to create new Fore.com project by using Eclipse. but i am getting the error prompt "Unable to connect to hostname 'test.salesforce.com' . Invalid Username, password, security token,or user locked out".

Note: I am trying to logging with my developer account by which i am practicing salesforce. My query is, do we need an organizational account to use eclipse or we can use the developer account also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to connect to your devloper account, then the url is not '`test.salesforce.com`', you have to use the url : `login.salesforce.com`.

In The Environment picklist just choose `Production/Developer Edition` and it should work

[image]

Comment: I dont have security token. Is there any way by which i can get the security token. Rest other thing i am trying the same. I tried with login.salesforce.com too and set the environment as Production/Developer Edition also but its not working.

Comment: you can generate your Security token by clicking (in your Salesforce Org):

`YourName -> MySettings -> Personal -> Reset My Security Token` , and it will send  you an email with the new Security token

Comment: Hi Ihssan, Thanks for your help. that error is resolved but i am getting i new error "Destination URL not set. The URL Return from login must be set in the SforceService. TO ignore this error create an empty Force.comProject without connecting to the server. click Create offline. "

Comment: can you try rebooting eclipse ?

Comment: Thanks It works for me . your replies helped me to clear my doubts and hope it will help others too, who they all are beginners.